# Is it possible to construct explicitely a homologue between two smooth simplicial cycles $A,B$ in a manifold that satisfy $\int_A w = \int_B w$?

Tags: differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose that $M$ is a compact manifold, and $[A]$ and $[B]$ are two cycles in the (real coefficients) homology of $M$ that are represented by smooth simplices $A$ and $B$. If we assume that $\int_A w = \int_B w$ for each closed differential form, then I think it follows from De Rham's theorem that $[A] = [B]$. But is it possible to build out of this data the simplex $ s : \Delta \to M$ that has as boundary $A - B$?

Comment: Do you really want $[A]$ and $[B]$ to be represented by single simplices, rather than some linear combination of smooth simplices? In any case, there is little reason to expect that $A-B$ is the boundary of a single simplex $s$, rather than some linear combination of simplices.

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right. I guess closer to the truth of what I want is a way to find a submanifold with $A - B$ as boundary, so that I could explain $\int_A w = \int_B w$ for all closed $w$ by applying stokes theorem directly. Maybe there are some subtleties with homology if that connecting manifold cannot be triangulated? At least in the case of surfaces I would be happy with an interpretation like this...